# Entity Framework return one field

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm working through some Entity Framework Tutorials and have arrived at the following for returning one value from a database.

```
string buf = ViewBag.quotationnumber;
using (var context = new myContext())
{
    var q = context.Projects.Where(s => s.quotationnumber==buf).FirstOrDefault<Projects>();
    ViewBag.CustomerName = q.CustomerName;
}
```

Is there a less verbose way to express this using the standard tooling? Or is encapsulating the above logic the best options?

Comment: You could just do `context.Projects.FirstOrDefault(s => s.quotationnumber==buf);`

Comment: Can you elaborate, what you mean by _less verbose way_? You always can write your own, domain specific, extension methods for DbSets.

Comment: In your particular case where you want only `CustomerName` you don't need to load all columns from the database. `name = context.Projects.Where(s => s.quotationnumber==buf).Select(s => s.CustomerName).FirstOrDefault();`

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you to take a look at repository and unit of work patterns, these two option in addition of generic repositories make your code super clear.

For finding a database context you can either use this method.

```
DbSet<TEntity>.Find(Object[])
```

[More about this find method.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1.find?view=efcore-2.1)

Comment: `Find` expects to get primary keys of the records. I afraid `quotationnumber` is not a primary key.

Comment: I think it depends on your design. If you want to identify this object with that key, it should be unique, otherwise you might get more than one result from database and then the first or default method will return first object from the list which is returned from the database.

Comment: `Find` will always return only one object or `null`.